FME: Create a copy of a GDB (Writer) and rename it after the Reader/Input (ITF)
Reader: ITF (abc.itf)
Writer: GDB (original.gdb)
I am reading an ITF File (abc.itf) and then write in an empty FGDB (original.gdb).
How can I create a copy of the FGDB with the name of the ITF (abc.gdb) and then write in it?
I am using FeatureWriter Parameters and FeatureType Writers.


